# Python Replace special characters in a CSV with specified string

Tags: python, string, csv, replace

I'm trying to replace multiple strings (with multiple language characters) in a csv file.

The following code works assuming that I rename my csv files using the `.txt` extension and then rename back to `.csv`. I'm wondering if the csv can be read and written directly.

```
import io

match = {
    "太好奇了": "First String",
    "धेरै एक्लो": "Second String",
    "심각하게 생명이 필요하다": "Third String"
}

f = io.open("input.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-16")
data = f.read()

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text


data = replace_all(data, match)
w = open("updated.txt", "w", encoding="utf-16")
w.write(data)
```

Comment: The extension of the file shouldn't matter as long as you treat it the same. It just needs to have the same encoding.

Comment: Did you try simply replacing `input.txt` with your csv file?

Comment: DANG. It worked.  What wrong I was doing before? It was duplicating entries and the file size was doubling and I thought CSV requires some special csv library to read write.

Comment: No idea, maybe you were appending to the same file?

Comment: I am not well familiar with it, definitely doing wrong (Probably r+) or was missing utf-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A csv file is nothing else than a simple txt file that is meant to represent a data table by separating the values by commas. This allows programs to read it efficiently into data using libraries like Python's `csv`.

Since it still is just a text file, you can also open it as a usual txt using a simple function like `open` and use it the exact same way you would use a txt file.

```py
f = open("myfile.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-16")
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

Note that file extensions actually change nothing about the file, they just signal how the file should be used. You could call a text file `myfile.kingkong` and it would still behave the same with the `open` function. In the same way, renaming `.csv` to `.txt` does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Use `pandas`.

Here's some code to help you get started.

```py
import pandas as pd

filename = 'data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-16')

# this will replace "太好奇了" with "First String"
df.replace(to_replace="太好奇了", value="First String")

df.to_csv('update.csv') # save result
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One place to define multiple strings would be nice, though using multiple df.replace suffices my requirement. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Bunny `pandas` is way too overkill for a simple character replacement like this.